# Given an arbitrary string, how can I shell out the command to bash?

Tags: go

I have a pretty basic golang question.

Given an arbitrary string like `"echo foo"`, or `"CGO_ENABLED=0 go build -o ./bin/echo -a main.go"`, what is the idiomatic way to parse/run that command using `os/exec`?

The way that I got this working seems pretty hacky, and I'm looking for a more idiomatic approach.

```
userInput = "CGO_ENABLED=0 go build -o ./bin/echo -a main.go"
command := exec.Command("/bin/bash", "-c", userInput)
out, err := command.Output()
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
 }
```

Comment: If you have no fancy quoting rules to follow then something like `f := strings.Fields(x)` then `os.Exec`'s `exec.Command(f[0], f[1:]...)` should work.

Comment: By the way, your example names the variable "userInput"… never pass user input directly to a shell (or otherwise "run" it) without doing strict checking/sanitation unless you like giving the current processes' full permissions away to anyone that can provide it input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how arbitrary and flexible your `userInput` string is, I might do something like this.

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    if err := os.Setenv("FOO", "bar"); err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }

    // As Dave C pointed out, exec.Command does this for you.
    // goAbsPath, err := exec.LookPath("go")
    // if err != nil {
    //   log.Println(err)
    // }

    // Pass whatever other arguments necessary.
    cmd := exec.Command("go", "version")
    if err = cmd.Run(); err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
}
```

If nothing else, maybe `os.Setenv` and `exec.LookPath` might be useful to know about.

Comment: Why directly muck with `LookPath`? Didn't you read the [`exec.Command` documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Command) that clearly states it will do that for you when required?

Comment: Also, there is a difference between passing a new environment to *only* a child (via say setting `cmd.Env`) and setting the current processes' environment (which will, by default, get inherited by all future child processes) with `os.Setenv`.

Comment: Thanks, Dave C. No, I didn't read the `exec.Command` documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I may write like this:

```
cmd := exec.Command(cmdName, arg1, arg2, ..)   
cmd.Env = append(cmd.Env, "foo=bar")

err = cmd.Start()
if err != nil {
    // log or something else
}

err = cmd.Wait()
if err != nil {
    if exitErr, ok := err.(*exec.ExitError); ok {
        if status, ok := exitErr.Sys().(syscall.WaitStatus); ok {
            // handle err according to different status.ExitStatus()
        }
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
// ...
```

Godoc explains quite well if you need more details.